# Using a pre-defined method to change a property of an object Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which is defined before the object was created. This pre-defined function uses the 'this' keyword to change the value of a property in the object. Inside the object I have a method that calls the predefined method with one argument. However after calling this method and I try to print the value of the property that was supposed to be changed, it still remains the same. How do I fix this?

```
var setName = function(yourName){
    this.name = "Your name is " + yourName;
};

// create an object called `human`
var human = {
    name: "Nothing here yet",
    setHumanName: function(name) {
        setName(name);//Name should be changed now
    }
};

human.setHumanName("Emeka");
console.log(human.name); //this does not print the new value of name
```

Comment: Have you checked the JS console? If I recall it correctly, `setName` meaning for `this` is not what you expect, and you will be getting "invalid property" errors.

Comment: I get no errors, but when I try to console.log(name) inside the setHumandName function, it prints the correct value for name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
var human = {
    name: "Nothing here yet",
    setHumanName: setName // no invocation, only assigning the function
};
```

For explicitly invoking arbitrary functions *on* an object (so that their [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is set to that object) use the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) of the function.

Comment: Oh wow ^ That is the way we were told to do it but I either got an error message when I tried it previously or just forgot to do it this way. Now that looks a lot simpler than the other answer and more at my level. Thanks to the both of you that have posted answers

Answer (score 2):

You should call the function in object context:

```
setHumanName: function(name) {
    setName.call(this, name);
}
```

Comment: @Smac89 [calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)